# How to pass query strings for to params for requests.get?

Tags: python

Given is a string:

```
'search=hello+world&status=something&cache=false'
```

How do I pass parameters and values from that string to a payload dictionary given that I'm not sure what parameters I will always get from the string in order to use it in requests.get()?

```
requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `dict` *comprehension*:

```
def split_params(param_string):
   return {param: value for param, value in (pair.split('=') for pair in param_string.split('&'))}

split_params('search=hello+world&status=something&cache=false')
```

Output:

```
{'search': 'hello+world', 'status': 'something', 'cache': 'false'}
```

This is based off the observation that each param-value pair is separated externally by an `&` and internally by an `=`.

Answer (score 1):

you can give as follows

> ```
> url = url + '?'+ your_parm_string
> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = 'search=hello+world&status=something&cache=false'
params = string.split('&')
payload = {}
for params in param:
    p = param.split('=')
    payload[p[0]] = p[1]
print(payload)
{'search': 'hello+world', 'status': 'something', 'cache': 'false'}
```